# Perfomance in Hibernate 4.2 with @OneToMany - Unidirectional vs Bidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate

I need only a unidirectional relationship OneToMany, but in Terms of performance I want to ask what is the best practice?.

I did a test with Junit, and the result with bidirectional is: 1.9s and the unidirectional code 2.4s, it seems for unidirectional needs more time

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.21

@Unidirectional 2.4s

**Parent.class**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "parentuni_id")  
private Set<ChildUni> childs;

Hibernate: select nextval ('parentuni_seq')
Hibernate: select nextval ('childuni_seq')
Hibernate: select nextval ('childuni_seq')
Hibernate: insert into parentuni (parentuni_name, parentuni_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into childuni (childuni_name, childuni_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into childuni (childuni_name, childuni_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update childuni set parentuni_id=? where childuni_id=?
Hibernate: update childuni set parentuni_id=? where childuni_id=?
```

@Bidirectional 1.9s

**Parent.class**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<Child> childs;
```

**Child.class**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
private Parent parent;

Hibernate: select nextval ('parent_seq')
Hibernate: select nextval ('child_seq')
Hibernate: select nextval ('child_seq')
Hibernate: insert into parent (parent_name, parent_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Child (child_name, parent_id, child_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Child (child_name, parent_id, child_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Hibernate best practices](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/best-practices.html), it says

**Prefer bidirectional associations:**

- **Unidirectional associations are more difficult to query**. In a large application, almost all associations must be navigable in both directions in queries.

Helpful sources : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/hibernate-mapped-collections.html

Hope this helps.